# Emitting to all clients when a variable reaches a specific value

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to create a basic TCG style game with Node/Vue/Socket.io and can't seem to figure out how to emit to both clients when a "ready" count = 2 but with different data, I'll explain a little below...

The sequence of events is as such:
player connects -> server sends player a "deck" -> player clicks ready to start and also sends back their first 'card'.. Then the server should send out to each player the other players first card. (Note my emit events don't have the correct titles atm - they were already written up on the front end so just kept them the same)

On connection I've pushed to an array called sockets, that I was using for testing. Then in the "ready" event I created an array called "firstCards" that I'm pushing the socket event data to then adding a .socket property to it (to signify who's who), then incrementing ready.

I've had a little bit of a play around with a few different methods but I can only seem to get the last card sent to both clients as opposed to each client getting the other clients first.. I also tried just putting the "if" statement outside of the socket event (as you will see below with the comment on the brackets/curly braces) which doesn't seem to work either.
I haven't tried this kind of asymmetric data transfer before and unsure if that is even the correct term... or whether this is even the correct way to do so, any help would be much appreciated!

This is the code I'm using so far:

```js
socket.on('ready-up', function (card)
{
    console.log(`Player ${socket.id} is ready`);
    ready++;
    console.log(ready);
    card.socket = socket.id;
    firstCards.push(card);
    console.log(firstCards);
});
if (ready == 2)
{
    for (let i = 0; i < sockets.length; i++)
    {
        io.to(sockets[i]).emit('p2hand', "Both players ready");
        let opp = sockets.find(element => element != socket.id);
        console.log(`Socket ID is: ${socket.id}`);
        console.log(`Opp ID is: ${opp}`);
        let card = firstCards.find(element => element.socket == opp)
        console.log(card);
        io.to(opp).emit('reveal',
        {
            'name': card.name,
            'hp': card.hp,
            'mp': card.mp,
            'skills': card.skills,
            'icon': card.icon
        });
        //       io.to(opp).emit('reveal', card);
        ready = 0;
    }
}
//      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this one out for anyone who may end up wanting to do what I was trying to do....

I decided that upon connection, both clients join a room called "game1".
The server will then emit "firstCards" to that room.

After that it was just a case of making sure the player-client know which was the opponents card... Now I could have used the .name property for this, but I decided to add an "id" property using the socket.id instead due to the possibility of the same card being drawn for both players.

I'm thinking that all server-client interactions will now have to carry this property for any other cards in the game such as items, spells, etc